# sum of positive integers in a array C

Tags: c, arrays, sum

I'm trying to find the sum of all positive numbers in an array.  So far, I have come up with this;

```
int largest_sum_sequence(int list, int size)
{
    int sum = 0, *index = 0;
    for (index < size; index = size; index++)
    {
        if (list[index] > 0)
        {
            sum = sum + list[index];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
    return sum;
}
```

My program keeps crashing.  I'm pretty sure it has something to do with index.  Whenever I use list[index] it says that I need to use a pointer for index, but I don't know how to do that properly.  Help is appreciated!

Comment: you are passing in 2 ints.  You intent for the list to be an int *. And the index should not be a pointer.

Comment: Perfect thanks!  I figured it was me doing something stupid like that.  We just started doing arrays in class so I'm still struggling with them.

Comment: this line: for (index < size; index = size; index++) is NOT the way to write a 'for' statement. The sequence is initializer; continue condition; stepper.  so the statement should be: 
    for (index=0; index < size; index++)

Comment: this line: int largest_sum_sequence(int list, int size) should be: int largest_sum_sequence(int *list, int size)

Answer (score 0):

You do not want index to be a pointer, and your for loop is incorrect.  Try:

```
int sum = 0, index = 0;
for (; index < size; index++)
```

Comment: if I do that, every time I use list[index] it won't build properly.  Tells me that index "must have pointer-to-object type".

Comment: Heh.  What a confusing message.  At the root of it, as Jeff says, you want an int* as your 'list'.  The reason the compiler says that 'index' must have a pointer-to-object type is that array subscripting is commutative in C.

Answer (score 0):

Function argument doesn't except an array.
Quick function I wrote.

```
int getSums(int myArray[], int size)
{
    int total = 0;
    int index = size;
    for ( int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        if (myArray[i] > 0)
            total += myArray[i];
    }

    return ( total );
};
```

Comment: Hello. Please test your code, you will find it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tells you actually exactly what to do.
First of all you need an array or a pointer as a parameter, like

```
int largest_sum_sequence(int *list, int size)
{
    ....
}
```

or

```
int largest_sum_sequence(int list[], int size)
{
    ....
}
```

where the latter might be easier to read.

The second thing is, you don't want to iterate with a pointer through the list, but more with a simple integer.

so you declare

```
int sum = 0, index = 0;
```

The for() loop isn't quite correct either. Instead of initializing something, you test if `index < size` and discard the result. This is syntactically correct, but doesn't make sense.

The first part in the for-statement is executed before the loop starts, but doesn't influence the starting itself. It is meant for initializing the loop variable (index in this case). The second part is the termination condition. The loop terminates if the condition evaluates to false. The last part of the loop is for incrementing (or decrementing, more abstract, changing) the loop variable.

Having said this, it is halfway obvious it should look like:

```
for (index = 0; index < size; ++index) {
    ....
}
```

Assuming your list isn't very long (such that the sum could exceed `2^{31} - 1`), the rest is correct. Although I'd add an `\n` to the printf() pattern.

Where is the list coming from? Can't answer that from your code, but you've room for mistakes here too :-)